# Hide div after 15seconds of mouseout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

On my website a pop-up is appeared on page load, i've three conditions :

1. After page load if there is no any action on pop-up div within 15 seconds then it'll be hide automatically.
2. After page load if mouse became out side the pop-up div then div will be hide after 15sec of mouseout.
3. After page load if mouse is located on pop-up then pop-up will not be hide till mouseout.

code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Action on mouseover from pop-up
    $('#activity').on("mouseover", function(e) {
        ('#activity').show();
    });

    // Action on mouseout from pop-up
    $('#activity').on("mouseout", function() {
        setTimeout(function() { $("#activity").fadeOut(1500); }, 15000);
    });
setTimeout(function() { $("#activity").fadeOut(1500); }, 15000)
})
```

Comment: what is your problem with your code now??

Comment: on mouseover my pop-up became hide after 15seconds of page load..

Comment: Remove last line in `$(document).ready` i.e.  `setTimeout(function() { $("#activity").fadeOut(1500); }, 15000)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just using the .show() function won't stop the timeout function you've called. You need to clear the timeout function on mouseover.

This will set the timeout to a variable named `timeout` when the page has loaded, or reset it on mouseoff. If you mouseover the activity then that timeout function will be cleared (cancelled) and restarted when you mouseoff

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var timeout;

    // Action on mouseover from pop-up
    $('#activity').on("mouseover", function(e) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    });

    // Action on mouseout from pop-up
    $('#activity').on("mouseout", function() {
        timeout = setTimeout(function() { $("#activity").fadeOut(1500); }, 15000);
    });

    timeout = setTimeout(function() { $("#activity").fadeOut(1500); }, 15000)
});
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        // Action on mouseover from pop-up
        $('#activity').on("mouseover", function(e) {
            $('#activity').show();
        });

        // Action on mouseout from pop-up
        $('#activity').on("mouseout", function() {
            setTimeout(function() { $("#activity").fadeOut(1500); }, 15000);
        });
    setTimeout(function() { $("#activity").fadeOut(1500); }, 15000)
    })
```

or add **$** in this line

```
$('#activity').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Action on mouseover from pop-up
$('#activity').mouseover(function(e) {
    $('#activity').show();
});

// Action on mouseout from pop-up
$('#activity').mouseout(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { $("#activity").fadeOut(1500); }, 15000);
});

});
```

You let the actitvity fade out anyway because of your last line of code...

Comment: OP stated that if there was no activity on the pop-up div after 15 seconds, he wanted it to be removed. That last line accomplished that